# Use ? in URL rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

htaccess which is working fine..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|images|js|jquery|highslide) - [L]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9])$ products.php?ac=viewProduct&id=$3&cid=0 [L]
```

Now I want want my URL like this.

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/?id=([0-9])$ products.php?ac=viewProduct&id=$3&cid=0 [L]
```

Means i want to add `?id=` in my URL after last .. But it is not working.

I have also tried backslash before `?`

Can any one pls help?

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` directive is not able to receive the query string, and therefore, you can not parse it in the expression.

You'd have to rely on the `RewriteCond` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(css|images|js|jquery|highslide) - [L]

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9])$ products.php?ac=viewProduct&id=$3&cid=0 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/$ products.php?ac=viewProduct&id=%1&cid=0 [L]
```

Comment: Should we be using a similar approach in `.htaccess` for [our issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41205369/1527780). Could you please have a look and probably leave a suggestion/solution?