# In PHP, how to preserve 1st part of a link, keep 2nd and dynamically change the rest

Tags: php, url-rewriting, preg-replace, preg-match

Foe example. Lets take 4 URLs (existing or future) that follow the targeted pattern of:
`https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/ThisWillBeDifferent/ThisWillNot`
`https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/ThisIsDifferent/ThisWillNot`
`https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/ChangedAgain/ThisWillNot`
`https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/AndAgain/ThisWillNot`

So. **If any** of these (existing or future) links is **clicked**, we need them to be changed to:
`https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/WhateverThisWillBe/ThisWillNot?SomethingHere`

This means:
If one clicks on a link that starts with `https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/`, keep this part, add the part `WhateverThisWillBe` (which extends until you find the next `/`), add `/ThisWillNot?` (notice the `?`) and finally add `SomethingHere`

Should I probably be using `.htaccess`

Please keep in mind that although it is about a WordPress site, I can figure the `SomethingHere` which is WordPress related but have a difficult time figuring out how to keep the first part intact when the second `WhateverThisWillBe` part is different (in every single link) and add `/ThisWillNot?` after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using preg_replace:

```
preg_replace('~(https://KeepThisPartTill-cde.com/a/b/cde/).+?(/ThisWillNot)~i',
             "$1WhateverThisWillBe$2?",
              $string);
```